# My textbook says that $f(x)$ and $\sqrt{f(x)}$ have the same period. Why isn't this true for $\sin x$ and $\sin^2x$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

> It says on my textbook that the period of $f(x)$ is the same as the period of $\sqrt{f(x)}$. Then why isn't the period of $\sin x$ the same as $\sin^2x$?

I don't know what I'm missing. Am I right in assuming that the square root of $\sin^2x$ is $\sin x$?

Comment: The square root of $y^2$ is $|y|$ ...

Comment: ...and $|\sin x|$ has period $\pi$, the same as $\sin^2x$.

Comment: Thank you for the edits. Didn't know how to use latex.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thank you. Will check it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The square root of $\sin^2 (x)$ is $|\sin(x)|$, since the square root function on the reals is defined to be the *positive* square root.

Comment: Ok. I thought it would be +sinx after rejecting -sinx. Thank you.